# Avro with Java 8 dates as logical type

Tags: java, java-8, avro

Latest Avro compiler (1.8.2) generates java sources for [dates logical types](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/spec.html#Date) with [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) based implementations. How can I configure Avro compiler to produce sources that used Java 8 date-time API?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Currently (avro 1.8.2) this is not possible. It's hardcoded to generate Joda date/time classes.

The current `master` branch has switched to Java 8 and there is an [open issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-2079) (with [Pull Request](https://github.com/apache/avro/pull/248)) to add the ability to generate classes with `java.time.*` types.

I have no idea on any kind of release schedule for whatever is currently in `master` unfortunately. If you feel adventurous you can apply the patch to `1.8.2`, since in theory it should all be compatible. The underlying base types when serializing / deserializing are still integers and longs.

Answer (score 6):

You need to create your own [Conversion](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/api/java/org/apache/avro/Conversion.html)s to support java-8 date-time api, below is a conversion for `java.time.LocalDate`:

```
class Java8LocalDateConversion extends Conversion<LocalDate> {
    @Override
    public Class<LocalDate> getConvertedType() {
        return LocalDate.class;
    }

    @Override
    public String getLogicalTypeName() {
        //      v--- reuse the logical type `date`
        return "date";
    }

    @Override
    // convert LocalDate to Integer
    public Integer toInt(LocalDate value, Schema schema, LogicalType type) {
        return (int) value.toEpochDay();
    }

    @Override
    // parse LocalDate from Integer
    public LocalDate fromInt(Integer value, Schema schema, LogicalType type) {
        return LocalDate.ofEpochDay(value);
    }
}
```

The logical types can be reused in avro, so you can using the existing `date` logical type, for example:

```
Schema schema = LogicalTypes.date().addToSchema(Schema.create(Type.INT));
```

For the serializing & deserializing you should set the `GenericData` which will find your own conversion, for example:

```
//serializing
DatumWriter<T> out = new SpecificDatumWriter<>(schema, data());

// deserializing
DatumReader<T> in = new SpecificDatumReader<>(schema, schema, data());

private SpecificData data() {
    SpecificData it = new SpecificData();
    it.addLogicalTypeConversion(new Java8LocalDateConversion());
    return it;
}
```

If you don't want to configure the `GenericData` every time, you can use the global `GenericData` instead, for example:

```
//      register the conversion globally ---v
SpecificData.get().addLogicalTypeConversion(new Java8LocalDateConversion());
```

Comment: here is the test I wrote on [github](https://github.com/holi-java/api-tests/blob/6d09966f007bd6ea6089a5f638275ae0ff5b2a67/avro/src/test/java/test/avro/AvroTypesTest.java#L51_L55).

Comment: It doesn't solve a problem: avro compiler still generate joda's date field for such logical type.

Answer (score 2):

- use Avro version >= `1.9.0` < `1.10.0`
- add  `<dateTimeLogicalTypeImplementation>jsr310</dateTimeLogicalTypeImplementation>`
  into `configuration` section.
- use Avro version >= `1.10.0`
- java8/jsr310 native date/time classes used by default

Answer (score 1):

With avro 1.9.2 you can use e.g. [date](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Date) for `LocalDate`:

```
    {
      "name": "Transaction",
      "type": "record",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "time",
          "type": {
            "type": "int",
            "logicalType": "date"
          }
        },
```

See [Logical Types](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Logical+Types) for the other types.

Answer (score 1):

[Avro v1.11.0 TimeConversions](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.0/api/java/org/apache/avro/data/TimeConversions.html) has built-in support for Java 8 time classes such as `LocalDate`, `Instant`, etc.  The `TimeConversions` must be registered with the `SpecificData` class or its sub-classes, such as `ReflectData`.  Here is a complete example of how to use `TimeConversions`:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Account
{
    private int id;
    private LocalDate createdOn;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        // create schema from POJO Account class
        ReflectData reflectData = ReflectData.get();
        reflectData.addLogicalTypeConversion(new TimeConversions.DateConversion());
        Schema schema = reflectData.getSchema(Account.class);
        System.out.println("Schema in JSON:\n" + schema + "\n");

        // create avro writer
        DatumWriter<Account> datumWriter = new ReflectDatumWriter<>(schema);
        DataFileWriter<Account> dataFileWriter = new DataFileWriter<>(datumWriter);
        // dataFileWriter.setCodec(CodecFactory.snappyCodec()); // for compression
        dataFileWriter.create(schema, new File("accounts.avro"));
        dataFileWriter.append(new Account(123, LocalDate.of(2001, 1, 1)));
        dataFileWriter.append(new Account(234, LocalDate.of(2002, 2, 2)));
        dataFileWriter.close();

        // create avro reader
        DatumReader<Account> datumReader = new ReflectDatumReader<>(schema);
        DataFileReader<Account> dataFileReader = new DataFileReader<>(new File("accounts.avro"), datumReader);
        dataFileReader.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AVRO 1.10 added support for `LocalDateTime`, see [Apache Avro™ 1.10.0 Specification](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.10.0/spec.html#Local+timestamp+%28millisecond+precision%29)

Comment: There is no such thing as "LocalDateTime" on the page you referenced.

Comment: I meant "Local timestamp". This gets translated into "LocalDateTime" in Java.