# Avro - how to register custom LogicalType for SpecificCompiler

Tags: java, avro, avro-tools

hey avro users and specialists,

i want to use avro logicalTypes, means creating some on my own - not only using built in ones.

The question is **how to get the compiler generating code from schema to use my own created ones**.

i created my schema (relevant part):

```
{
  "name": "street",
  "type": {
    "type": "string",
    "logicalType": "custom-street"
  },
  "doc": "Street format ending with house number"
}
```

(and of course created type and conversion, see https://github.com/markush81/avro-examples)

and i have now no clue **how to configure the compiler to use it**.

I use the compiler via gradle plugin (but i guess this is not making any difference at first place)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.commercehub.gradle.plugin.avro' version '0.14.2'
}

avro {
    enableDecimalLogicalType = true //enable built-in decimal type
}
```

Thanks for any hints (or workarounds).

P.S.: Of course i know how to manipulate the generated classes to support my logical type (see: https://github.com/markush81/avro-examples/tree/master/src/main/manual), but this would mean i can never re-compile from my schema definitions.

Comment: did you take a look to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712231/avro-with-java-8-dates-as-logical-type? I think you can implement the conversion and add it globaly like this before serialize/desieralize your data SpecificData.get().addLogicalTypeConversion(new Java8LocalDateConversion()); I do not think this will be part of the compiled class

Comment: yep i know this one, but it is not related to my problem. It is about serializing and deserializing and not about schema compiler.

Comment: can you provide example of what you are expecting?

Comment: sure. my expectation is: when running gradle build i expect build/generated-classes to have my logicalTypes as i did manually in src/main/manual. So for current example: in Adress.java there is Street instead of String type.

Answer (score 1):

After searching a lot in the [avro code](https://github.com/apache/avro) 1.8.2 i came to the conclusion that at the moment the compiler tool is not made to support custom logicalTypes **for code generation**.

If we have a look at `record.vm` velocity template

```
#if ($this.hasLogicalTypeField($schema))
    protected static final org.apache.avro.data.TimeConversions.DateConversion DATE_CONVERSION = new org.apache.avro.data.TimeConversions.DateConversion();
    protected static final org.apache.avro.data.TimeConversions.TimeConversion TIME_CONVERSION = new org.apache.avro.data.TimeConversions.TimeConversion();
    protected static final org.apache.avro.data.TimeConversions.TimestampConversion TIMESTAMP_CONVERSION = new org.apache.avro.data.TimeConversions.TimestampConversion();
    protected static final org.apache.avro.Conversions.DecimalConversion DECIMAL_CONVERSION = new org.apache.avro.Conversions.DecimalConversion();

    private static final org.apache.avro.Conversion<?>[] conversions = new org.apache.avro.Conversion<?>[] {
    #foreach ($field in $schema.getFields())
        ${this.conversionInstance($field.schema())},
    #end
       null
    };

    @Override
    public org.apache.avro.Conversion<?> getConversion(int field) {
        return conversions[field];
    }
#end
```

there are only four conversions added, the ones provided by avro itself.

Another piece to look at is in `org.apache.avro.compiler.specific.SpecificCompiler`

```
  public String conversionInstance(Schema schema) {
      if (schema == null || schema.getLogicalType() == null) {
           return "null";
      }

      if (LogicalTypes.date().equals(schema.getLogicalType())) {
           return "DATE_CONVERSION";
      } else if (LogicalTypes.timeMillis().equals(schema.getLogicalType())) {
           return "TIME_CONVERSION";
      } else if (LogicalTypes.timestampMillis().equals(schema.getLogicalType())) {
           return "TIMESTAMP_CONVERSION";
      } else if (LogicalTypes.Decimal.class.equals(schema.getLogicalType().getClass())) {
           return enableDecimalLogicalType ? "DECIMAL_CONVERSION" : "null";
      }

      return "null";
}
```

there is also no part where custom logicalTypes could be added at all.

Answer (score 1):

Since Avro 1.9.x there is now the possibility to register custom `logicalType` and `conversion`.

Main point is to write

- LogicalType
- LogicalTypeFactory
- Conversion

With maven and gradle there is also support to generated code with your custom types from avro schema. See example at https://github.com/markush81/avro-examples.

Gradle Plugin Configuration

```
plugins {
    id 'com.commercehub.gradle.plugin.avro' version '0.18.0'
}

avro {
    enableDecimalLogicalType = true
    dateTimeLogicalType = "JSR310"
    stringType = "CharSequence"
    outputCharacterEncoding = "UTF-8"
    logicalTypeFactory("street", de.mh.examples.avro.StreetLogicalTypeFactory)
    customConversion(de.mh.examples.avro.StreetConversion)
}
```

Comment: IMHO, this feature is only available in the Gradle plugin. There's an [open feature request](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-2621) for the Maven plugin to enable logical type registrations.

Comment: This is now also available in the Maven plugin - https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/lang/java/integration-test/codegen-test/pom.xml gives an example.